# Как сделать архив сайта на wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Делаю это первый раз, не хочу ошибиться. У меня есть шаблон сайта на Worpdress, который установлен на OpenServer. Как мне правильно сделать архив этого шаблона, чтобы выставить его на стоки? Нужно отметить, что это именно шаблон, каждый купивший его - будет изменять этот шаблон под себя (изображения, некоторые блоки и т.д.). Будет ли достаточно сделать обычный Экспорт инструментами Wordpress'а?

[image: Можно ли делать такой экспорт ?]

Comment: Прежде чем что-то продавать, надо выучить терминологию. В WordPress шаблон - один файл, отображающий некую сущность. То, что вы называете шаблоном - это тема.

Comment: Архив файлов делают с помощью утилиты zip.